# Last row with joins

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

```
Orders
OrderNo    OrderItems   CusID
5001       2            300001
5002       1            300001
5003       2            300002

OrderDetails
OrderDetailsNo     OrderNo   OrderItem
70001              5001      Hotdog
70002              5001      Pancake
70003              5002      Iced Tea
70004              5003      Bacon Sandwich
70005              5003      Ham
```

I use `select top 1 from Orders Order By OrderNo Desc` to get the last row if there is no joins.

```
OrderNo    OrderItems   CusID
5003       2            300002
```

How will I get the last result of Order with left outer join?

Result

```
OrderNo    OrderItems   CusID     OrderDetailsNo  OrderItem
5003       2            300002    70004           Bacon Sandwich
5003       2            300002    70005           Ham
```

Sample Outer join

```
select  Orders.OrderNo, OrderItems, CusID, OrderDetailsNo, OrderItem 
From Orders
left outer join
OrderDetails
on Orders.OrderNo = OrderDetails.OrderNo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select  Orders.OrderNo, OrderItems, CusID, OrderDetailsNo, OrderItem 
From (select top 1 * from Orders Order By OrderNo Desc) Orders
left outer join
OrderDetails
on Orders.OrderNo = OrderDetails.OrderNo
```

or

```
select top 1 with ties Orders.OrderNo, OrderItems, CusID, OrderDetailsNo, OrderItem 
From Orders
left outer join
OrderDetails
on Orders.OrderNo = OrderDetails.OrderNo
Order By Orders.OrderNo Desc
```

Comment: Added the tablename to the 2nd ORDER BY, now both should work

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH cte AS (
  SELECT TOP (1)
         orderno
       , orderitems
       , CusID
  FROM   orders
  ORDER
      BY orderno DESC
)
SELECT cte.orderno
     , cte.orderitems
     , cte.CusID
     , orderdetails.orderdetailsno
     , orderdetails.orderitem
FROM   cte
 LEFT
  JOIN orderdetails
    ON cte.orderno = orderdetails.orderno
```